# Does anyone know of any datasets which have audio and accents?

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to do an accent detection project.

Comment: I can guess, but you should probably expand the question to make it possible to answer.

Comment: For what language? What do mean with "accents": dialects, or the accents of second language speakers? Please specify!

Answer (score 3):

Do you want specific accentwise data or recording of people chatting in a normal scenario would do as well?

Here are some resources, hope you find them to be heplful,

There's [the CMU audio database](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/databases/) and [the speech accent archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/index.php)

Apart from this, you could use youtube videos and transcripts, or speeches in different accents and their transcripts, sports commentary would be a good source as well.

Another good source is vlogs, they are natural and varied when it comes to accent.